# const_string lib issue

Tags: c++, boost, const-string

I'm trying [const_string](http://conststring.sourceforge.net/) lib that looks not bad, but it crashes at runtime with access violation(atomic_count, operator++()). The test code:

```
#include <boost/const_string/const_string.hpp>
#include <boost/const_string/concatenation.hpp>

typedef boost::const_string<wchar_t> wcstring;

class Test
{
private:
    const wcstring &s1;
    const wcstring &s2;

public:
    Test()
        : s1(L"")
        , s2(L"")
    {
    }

    const wcstring &GetS1()
    {
        return s1;
    }

    const wcstring &GetS2()
    {
        return s2;
    }
};


Test t;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Test t;
    wcstring t1 = t.GetS1(); // crashes here
    wcstring t2 = t.GetS2();

    return 0;
}
```

It crashes only if t is global. If I move declaration into main(), it's ok.
System: VS 2010, boost v. 1.47.0

The question: Am I doing something wrong or is it problem of library / compiler?
Can someone recommend a more stable implementation of immutable strings for C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your instance of `Test` has initialized its *reference* data members as references to temporaries created from the literals `L""`.

Oops. The temporaries no longer exist by the time you try to use one of them in the copy constructor of `wcstring` at the line that crashes, so your references don't refer to anything.

I think `boost::const_string` should pretty much always be used by value, that's what it's for.

Comment: I have to admit ignorance in this one – `const` ref *can* bind to a temporary and thus extends its life-time in the current scope. What’s the scope here? The constructor? If that were the case, `const` ref would behave like a normal reference. What are the rules? (Does this merit a new question?)

Comment: @Konrad: yes, it's the body of the constructor. 12.2/5, "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits". This does make const reference data members slightly dangerous, I can't off-hand think of *any* situation in which you want a data member that's used in the constructor but nowhere else, so accidentally initializing them with a temporary almost guarantees something bad will happen at an undefined later date.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I see the problem now.

Comment: Too bad that this particular `const_string` constructor isn't explicit.

Comment: @dalle: maybe. It would stop people accidentally using a reference when they meant a value, but there might well be other uses where implicit conversion is needed. If a function takes `std::string`, it's kind of useful to be able to call it with a string literal instead with no cast, and although I haven't used `const_string` I assume the same holds there. If it was explicit then people could always write overloads for those functions, of course. I guess it depends whether you like weak typing - if not then you don't want anything to have non-explicit ctors.